# OS X dev: how to install a new font into the system

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

First of all, I know about ATSApplicationFontsPath property in Info.plist. But it adds custom fonts just for my application. And I want my app to install some fonts into the OS X during the first launch. That's because my app exports text and I have to make sure that user won't lose proper text formatting opening his file in some other app.

I saw this behavior in Final Draft app. It has custom fonts in its Resources folder. And its Info.plist has no ATSApplicationFontsPath property. But somehow after the first launch Final Draft installs those fonts into the system and uses them.

How is it possible? Didn't come any close to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the font files to ~/Library/Fonts or, with admin authentication, /Library/Fonts. You may also need to call `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs()` with `kCTFontManagerScopeUser` to make them immediately available to already-running apps (including your app which installs them).

I recommend that you ask permission from the user before installing anything "permanent" like this outside of your app.

Comment: I've been able to register my font throughout the system via CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs. Now every app can use my fonts as I want. But I can't copy font to ~/Library/Fonts. NSFileManager tell's "couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Fonts”". I guess it is a limitation of the sandbox rules. Pity.

Comment: Yes, you should mention if your app is sandboxed because that, by definition, will limit what it can do. The concern with registering fonts from within your app is what happens if your app is deleted.

Comment: I've tried to delete my app. Those fonts I registered within the app have simply disappeared in other apps.